# Merging data across multiple servers

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

OK, so I have this query that is used to record the stored procedure usage.  The problem is, I used the merge statement and it does not work across multiple servers to insert into a central table.  I basically need to have this generate the information on each server and then insert the data in a table on a central server.  Any input would be great on how to correct this issue.  We are using SQL 2008 R2.

```
MERGE INTO [DBA].dbo.SP_Exec_Stats_Table STAT
USING 
(
SELECT db.name as [DatabaseName]
    ,OBJECT_NAME(d.object_id, d.database_id) [ProcedureName] 
    ,d.last_execution_time
    ,o.modify_date
    ,d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time]
    ,d.execution_count
    ,@@SERVERNAME as [ServerName]
    ,d.object_id
FROM sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats AS d inner join sys.databases as db on db.database_id = d.database_id
    inner join sys.objects o on o.object_id = d.object_id
WHERE d.database_id not in(1,2,3,4,5) 
) as SRC
ON STAT.[Object_id] = SRC.Object_id
WHEN MATCHED 
 AND STAT.[Last_Exec_Time] <> SRC.last_execution_time THEN
UPDATE SET
    [Last_Exec_Time] = SRC.last_execution_time
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT  (DatabaseName 
,object_id
,[ProcedureName]
,[Last_Exec_Time]
,[Modified_Date]
,[Avg_Elapsed_Time]
,[Exec_Count]
,[Server_Name]
)
VALUES (SRC.DatabaseName 
    ,SRC.object_id
    ,SRC.[ProcedureName]
    ,SRC.last_execution_time
    ,SRC.modify_date
    ,SRC.[Avg_Elapsed_Time]
    ,SRC.execution_count
    ,SRC.[ServerName]
    ) ;
```

Comment: the target of the MERGE statement cannot be a remote table, but the source can very well be a table on a remote server. So perhaps you can modify your jobs to pull data from the remote servers and merge into the central server

Comment: I didn't even think to go that way.  Thanks, I re-wrote my statement and setup on the host server to look out at all the other servers and it worked great.  Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By re-writing the query to pull the information from the remote server and inserting it into the local server I was able to bypass the limitations of the MERGE statement.  I changed the 'from' to include the fully qualified name of the remote server and was able to pull the data into the local server.